# Extending VG > LVM

Tags: lvm, fdisk, cfdisk

I want to run an idea by you... I have an Ubuntu 16.04.3 with an LVM on a second drive I would like to extend. I want to complete this only using this CLI, no GUI. I have put my steps below how I complete this using gparted, if we can mimic these steps in the CLI.

I think what I am missing is honestly just whatever is the CLI equivalent to "Right-Click and extending it in gparted"

Here is a quick over of my setup view. In attempt to save some time and space I shortened some items. My steps will follow:

fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 170 GiB, 182536110080 bytes, 356515840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7fbfd5c7

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb2       1001470 293601279 292599810 139.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1001472 293601279 292599808 139.5G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/nextcloud--vg-root: 137.5 GiB, 147660472320 bytes, 
288399360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/nextcloud--vg-swap_1: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 
sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

vgdisplay:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               nextcloud-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  7
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               139.52 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              35717
  Alloc PE / Size       35717 / 139.52 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               huX2Hk-jG98-HieD-bAuV-Z0Wi-mAMi-nRGwDI
```

lvdisplay:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/nextcloud-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                nextcloud-vg
  LV UUID                TPebe1-nMhS-5kse-OR9G-IlGA-CBIc-QERaVE
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time nextcloud, 2016-07-27 13:27:51 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                137.52 GiB
  Current LE             35205
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/nextcloud-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                nextcloud-vg
  LV UUID                90e1zB-ZuSK-2wiV-webN-55Of-fD6H-8ex5M7
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time nextcloud, 2016-07-27 13:27:52 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

cat /proc/mounts | grep '^/':

```
  /dev/mapper/nextcloud--vg-root / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount ro,data=ordered 0 0
  /dev/sda1 /boot ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
```

pvs:

```
  PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sdb5  nextcloud-vg lvm2 a--  169.52g    0
```

All of this appears simple enough:

1. Boot to an ISO
2. Run gparted
3. Right-click "Deactivate" /dev/sdb5 (Sometimes I have to click this 2 or 3
4. times to make the key actually go away and allow changes. No errors are ever 
   thrown) < Is this normal?
5. Click "Apply"
6. Right-click, resize/move and extend the partition /dev/sdb2,
7. Right-click resize/move and extend the partition /dev/sdb5
8. Click "Apply"
9. lvextend –l +​100%FREE /dev/nextcloud-vg/root
10. reboot the machine
11. resize2fs /dev/nextcloud-vg/root

And I'm good.

EDIT - 1/3/18

If I try and accomplish the same thing through fdisk and CLI I cannot create the logical partition from the same sector. Details below

```
root@nextcloud:/home/ncadmin# fdisk /dev/sdb

Command (m for help): d
Partition number (2,5, default 5): 2

Partition 2 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): e
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 2
First sector (2048-367001599, default 2048): 1001470
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (1001470-367001599, default         367001599):

Created a new partition 2 of type 'Extended' and of size 174.5 GiB.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 1 extended, 3 free)
   l   logical (numbered from 5)
Select (default p): l

Adding logical partition 5
First sector (1003518-367001599, default 1003520):
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (**1003520**-367001599, default     367001599):
```

Comment: "with an LVM on a second drive" No, there's only one LVM and it's in the OS.

Comment: Only extending the partitions needs to be done with an external boot. The rest has been doable inside the OS for... at least the better part of a decade.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I mean second drive as in a second "physical" disk in VMware. /dev/sda just holds the MBR . I am good with booting to an ISO, no quarrels there. I would just like to do this without gparted...

Comment: So then use fdisk. Or sfdisk. Or whatever it is the cool kids are using these days.

Comment: I would if I understood how. If I try and use fdisk or cfdisk, there isn't an extend option. From I have read you can just delete the partition, then create new one, then write the changes. However, that deletes the lvm /dev/sda5.

Comment: have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409021/192320 but do not use `vgcreate`, use `vgextend` you can resize your _logical volume_ and the file system live without reboot **in one step**: `lvextend --resizefs -l +100%FREE /dev/nextcloud-vg/root`

Comment: Ok, I could give this a try but I feel like it wouldn't work. In my initial post of my `vgdisplay` the Free PE / Size is 0 / 0. It is not until I right-click and extend in gparted that this value becomes Free PE / Size 40 GIB. It may be that I am confused on how I could extend the logical volume when there appears to be no space to add to it.

Comment: @FaxMax I thought the wording of my comment would be enough, but that doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @ahoward you have to create new _physical extents_ and then you can add with `vgextend` the new free _PE_ to your _nextcloud-vg_

Comment: @ahoward please give us this information's: `cat /proc/mounts | grep '^/'`and `pvs`please edit your question.

Comment: @FaxMax updated question.

Answer (score -1):

umount the partition

```
umount /dev/sdb5
```

change the size of **/dev/sdb2** and **sdb5** (or use fdisk; https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/40702/how-to-manage-and-use-lvm-logical-volume-management-in-ubuntu/ )

```
cfdisk /deb/sdb
```

navigate with <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> to delete **sdb2** and **sdb5**.

Now you have to create a new (larger) extendet partition, **sdb2** with the same *start sector* **1001470** *(default value)* and the new maximum size *(default value)*. Create now a new **sdb5** inside of the new **sdb2** and use in your case again the default values. Change the type of **sdb5** to **8e** (linux lvm).
Until you don't use *write* is nothing changed on your disk.
After the changes, write it down to disk.

reload the partition tables with

```
partprobe
```

load/scan the lvm in your live system with (probably done automaticly by your system)

```
pvscan --verbose
vgscan --verbose
lvscan --verbose
```

now you can extend your physical volume for lvm with

```
pvresize --verbose /dev/sdb5
```

now you should see the new free PE with `vgdisplay`, if not scan again.
And now you can do the last step, resize your logical volume.

```
lvextend --resizefs -l +100%FREE --verbose /dev/nextcloud-vg/root
reboot
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the reply! I was apparently missing the idea of deleting the partition and re-creating it bigger. I am now running into an issue where I cannot create the logical partition at the correct sectors. I use fdisk /dev/sdb > delete sdb2 > create a new extended partition at sector 1001470 (**not the default value**) which works fine. However, when I go to create the logical partition I do not get the option of creating it at 1001472 (my current start sector) I only have the option to start it at sector 1003518.

Comment: @FaxMaxAdded a copy and paste from my CLI as an edit at the end of my original post

Comment: @ahoward i dont have a idea why you cant do it. But you can extend your lvm if you simple create a new primary partition `/dev/sdb3` and add this device to your logical volume group.

Comment: @FaxMaxI appreciate all the input. I understand I could extend the volume group over to another primary partition but those are limited.

Comment: It does not have to be a primary partition: LVM can use logical partitions just fine.

Comment: First step is wrong - `/dev/sdb5` isn't a mountable partition and so you cannot use `umount`. With an error at this point there's no way the rest can be trusted