# lvm and a partitioning question

Tags: partition, lvm, fdisk, pv

So when I do (as a root)

```
fdisk -l
```

I see `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`

Now I am practicing creating logical volumes, when I tried partitioning

```
/dev/sda2
```

I got two new partition `/dev/sda2p1` and `/dev/sda2p2`

and then I run

```
partprobe
```

but then when I try creating a pv

```
/dev/sda2p1 /dev/sda2p2
```

It says these devices are not found even though when I run

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda2
```

I do see them listed there (and I did chose type 8e when creating these partition lvm)

what am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Comment: I would probably be less confused if the text of your question included the command `pvcreate` anywhere within it :-P.    BTW you should really post both the command you use, and the exact error message, i.e. copy+paste.  It helps to minimize ambiguity, even if in this case the ambiguity was more about what you were trying to do and I may have found the technical problem anyway :-P.

Comment: PS: in case English is not your system language, you can (and should) use `export LC_ALL=C`, to temporarily get ASCII English messages and everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

LVM *Logical Volumes* are not created with `fdisk`.  You need to use `lvcreate` instead.

> I did chose type 8e when creating these partition lvm

Setting the partition type using fdisk, let you hint that a partition may contain an LVM *Physical Volume*.  Like setting any other partition type, this doesn't actually format the partition.  To format a partition as an LVM *Physical Volume*, you need to use `pvcreate`.

You do the `pvcreate` first.  Then assign it to a LVM *Volume Group*, for example creating a new VG using `vgcreate myvg /dev/sda2`.  Then you can create logical volumes.

You could go ahead and do this from the man pages, you shouldn't need to set any non-default option here, but it's probably easier to look for a nice tutorial which satisfies these critera :-P.

---

So what did you do?  Well, you effectively treated the partition `/dev/sda2` as a disk itself.  You formatted it with a partition table, and created partitions inside it.  Apparently `fdisk` is happy to let you do this without considering it a problem :).  However this isn't generally useful or something that people do.  BSD installs on PCs do something a bit like this, however Linux installers do not.  I tried creating something like sda2p1 myself.  My conclusion was the Linux kernel itself does not support nesting partition tables like this, although userspace commands can let you access them if you understand what's going on.

In my own testing, `partprobe /dev/sda8` failed.  It seemed confused, thinking that partitions were already being used, and reported errors on more partitions than existed anywhere on my system.  Instead, using `kpartx -av /dev/sda8` worked, in my case to detect and map "sda8p1".  However it appears the Linux kernel did not support nested partitions like this.[1]  The kernel was not aware of the block device `sda8p1`.  (It did not appear in `/sys/class/block` under that name).  Instead, the result of `kpartx` was to create a "device mapper" block device called `dm-0`.  It was created such that `cat /sys/block/dm-0/dm/name` showed `sda8p1`.

**Even after the `kpartx` command, my system did not create a device node at `/dev/sda8p1`.  Instead, the device node was accessible as `/dev/mapper/sda8p1`.**

(Or directly as `/dev/dm-0`.  `ls -l /dev/mapper` shows that the file(s) there are symbolic links to `/dev/dm-*`).

[1] Bonus fact: device nodes for `sda1` etc. have [pre-allocated device numbers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt).  There is no pre-allocated number for `sda2p1` etc.

Comment: I actually understand all of that, when I tried doing a pvcreate, it came up to me as devices are not available, i know that I have to use lvcreate, this is just a preparation, am preparing the partitions first and then i will use pvcreate, vgcreate and then lgcreate

Comment: @alkabary updated with test result.  I strongly suspect `/dev/sda2p1` does not actually exist.  To disprove this you would need to post the result of `ls /dev/sd*`, thanks.

Comment: I read your answer, it's very helpful. I included a screenshot and put it my question here. It did let me create it ! @sourcejedi

Comment: @alkabary haha.  What I'm telling you is that `fdisk` is making that up.  (The /dev/ part, to be specific). You have not posted the result of `ls /dev/sd*`.  I have no idea why you don't want to run that.

Comment: I also wish people wouldn't say my answers were very useful, when what they mean is: "this is an impressive wall of text but I'm not sure how I can _use_ this information to help me".  It's not very helpful.  I have edited to  **bold** the important part, since it ends up being at the end.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a physical harddisk e.g. `sda` or `sdb` 
A physical harddisk *can* contain a partition table.

you can add the whole disk to your `lvm`, then you don't need a partition table. e.g.:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda
```

or you create a partition table with `fdisk` or `cfdisk` after this you have to create the physical extents e.g.:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda5
```

the command `pvcreate`create physical extents now you have to create a **volume group**, a volume group contains many physical extents, a volume group can contain physical extents from one or many devices.

```
vgcreate VGName /dev/sda5
#          ^the name of your new volume group
#                    ^the partition or device
```

You can view with `vgs` the free space for your volume groups.

```
lvcreate -L 100G -n home VGName
#           ^size of your new logical volume
#                    ^with -n you can set a name e.g. home
#                          ^at the end the name of your VolumeGroup
```

You can use `lvcreate -l 100%FREE` if you like use your whole volume group or `lvcreate -l60%VG` for 60%

after you created a logical volume, you can create a filesystem e.g. ext4 `mkfs.ext4 /dev/VGName/home`